# Bibliography is not showing any entries

Tags: bibtex

I currently have a problem using the bibliography in `LaTeX`. I add it using a .bib file, but it does not show any references. I also run `LaTeX`, run `bibtex` and then run latex twice again. I have cited it in the main text, but also used the `\notice{*}` just to be sure. Below I have a MWE which shows the problem.

Thanks already for the help!

This is the main file that is the master document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [version=4] {mhchem}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\input{maintext.tex}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{testbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

\end{document}
```

This the .bib file:

`@book{Hesp,
    author    = "J. P. Hespanha",
    title     = "Linear Systems Theory",
    publisher = "Princeton",
    year      = "2009",
}`

And this is the text file that is use as an input

```
\chapter{main}
this is the main text \cite{Hesp}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example works for me! Apparently something different goes wrong. Do you have a generated `.bbl` file in your working directory?

Comment: Hi Cristian, I did have one for the real document though. But apparently something goes wrong with the building then I guess? Because for this example there is no .bbl file created.

I used the second option in the quick build menu (Pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex (2x) + vie pdf)

Comment: Laura329, I don't use such editors with `quick build menu`. I compile by hand always.

Comment: Christian, I did it by hand now, and when I compile BibTex, it tells me it can't open the test_main.aux file. That's my main document.

Comment: Do you have a `test_main.aux` file after the first pdflatex run?

Comment: Yes I have it after the first run

Comment: Run `bibtex test_main` then

Comment: When I do that I get the error: I couldn't open file name `build\test_main.aux

Comment: Ah: your file is in the directory `build`, not in the working directory. If you compile manually, I mean doing it in a console and typing `pdflatex test_main`. then `bibtex test_main` etc., not clicking on a button

Comment: It works! I never knew that you could build it using the console.. Certainly gives more information. I still had some entries that were commented out using % but apparently that gave problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's fine. Indeed, it's much more informative to have the console compilation. That's why I use it exclusively (and because I am really too old to switch to TeXStudio etc. ;-) )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cause of the problems were commented parts/commands in the O.P.'s document -- the problem is solved by tracking in the comments to the question.